# Handling system shutdown from application in Windows 7 embedded

Tags: c++, windows-7

We are developing an application for windows 7 embedded, we would like to control the shutdown procedure from the application iself without involving windows GUI.
After returning false in `afx_msg BOOL OnQueryEndSession( );` it immediatly prompt the user with the "Forced Shutdown" dialog.

Any of the following ways will solve our issue:

1. Is there a way to disable the "forced shutdown" dialog?
2. Any way to assign a custom
   behavior to the power button? (to run a script for example)
3. Is it possible to abort the shutdown before it starts to close services/applications?

Comment: This: https://msdn.microsoft.com/library/windows/desktop/aa376890 says use `ShutdownBlockReasonCreate`

Comment: [InitiateSystemShutdown](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/aa376873.aspx) with `dwTimeout=0`

Comment: @RichardCritten, I want the user to be able to confirm the shutdown. The option you suggested will shutdown the computer immidiatly

Comment: I think that last comment was meant to reply to LPs. Richard's suggestion is the correct one. If you want to block shutdown, call `ShowdownBlockReasonCreate`. When you're ready to allow it to proceed, call `ShutdownBlockReasonDestroy`. There is otherwise no magic switch to disable the dialog. Too many applications used to do this, effectively preventing the user from doing what they want with their machine. Don't get too carried away with this. They can always pull the plug if you're being unreasonable.

Comment: I did not note that in the question. The OS is Windows 7 embedded. I will edit now.